Can I replicate websocket request only with browser developer tools in python?
I'm quite new in this topic. I wonder is that possible to replicate websocket request in python using websocket lib by using only stuff that are available in developer tools of my browser.
If that's possible what I need from there to subscribe to sockets and listen to event? Or it's not enough and I have to do some reverse engineering skills? Any thoughts will be appreciated. Thank you :)
